# Wrap Function / Avoid repeating coid

Tags: c#, asynchronous, repeat

I'm new to c# and I have a (for me:) complex application with a grpc-interface.

I have about 20 (and rising) different functions where I pass different parameters and return different types:

```
private async Task<VersionOfInterfaceReply> Function1()
{
    ...
}

private async Task<ReturnInfoReply> Function2(
    List<NozzleToChange> nozzlelist,
    SideType side = SideType.Right,
    UInt32 processingarea = 1)
{
    ...
}
```

afterwards I want call,get,evaluate these testresults and repeat some functions.

```
{
    ResetTestResult();
    result = await Function1();
    if (result.success = true) { testresult.TestLog += $"message with variables of result\n"; }
    TestPassed(result);

    ResetTestResult();
    result = await Function2(x,y,z);
    if (result.success = true) { testresult.TestLog += $"{result.xy} message with variables of result\n"; }
    TestPassed(result);
}
```

result is already a dynamic variable (if you know better ways let me know)... but my question is following:

**How can I get rid of the** ResetTestResult(); **and** Testpassed(result) **with some kind of wrapping my functions?**

**Is this even possible with different output/parameter types and different amount of parameters**

I would like to have something like:

```
privat async Task? / or void CallFunction(Method givenMethod, string message)
{
    ResetTestResult();
    result = await givenMethod();
    if (result.success = true) { testresult.TestLog += $""+message +" with variables of result\n"; }
    TestPassed(result);
}

and call this like this:

{
    ...
    CallFunction(Function1(),"message1");
    CallFunction(Function2(x,y,z),"message2 {variable2}");
    ...
}
```

I tried understanding delegates, func, and actions, but im not really sure if this works for me. And another problem is the async part...

If you need any further information let me know.

thanks for your help in advance

kind regards
chris

Comment: Do your return types (`VersionOfInterfaceReply`, `ReturnInfoReply`) derive from the same base type / interface?

Comment: You can either use Reflection inside your "CallFunction" in order to call the function based on the specified name, or use Lambda expressions and pass the method invocation as parameter to "CallFunction (ex: () => Function1())

Comment: @JohnathanBarclay Some information in the replys is the same (success time message) but each one contains different data, sometimes a single value and sometimes a array of values

Comment: *"Avoid repeating coid"* <== What is "coid"?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `VersionOfInterfaceReply` and `ReturnInfoReply` implement an interface, such as:

```
interface IReply
{
    bool Success { get; }
}
```

You could write your method like this:

```
private async Task CallFunction<T>(Func<Task<T>> givenMethod, Func<T, string> message)
    where T : IReply
{
    ResetTestResult();
    T result = await givenMethod();
    if (result.Success) { testresult.TestLog += message(result); }
    TestPassed(result);
}
```

And use as follows:

```
await CallFunction(Function1, x => "message1");
await CallFunction(() => Function2(x, y, z), x => $"message2 {x.Variable2}");
```

To call methods with arguments, you can create a closure using a lambda expression.

[Working example](https://dotnetfiddle.net/iAc2GK)